# How do you delete a delayed_job within the job's class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

(Using collectiveidea's delayed_job)

I have a job that scrapes for a keyword, but I want the job to destroy itself if the keyword has since been deleted since it was enqueued (i.e. a user deletes one of his keywords).

```
class ScrapingJob < Struct.new(:keyword_id)
  def perform
      keyword = Keyword.find(keyword_id)
      data = keyword.scrape
      keyword.details.create!(:text => data[:text])
  end
end
```

I was trying to put it in DJ's before hook by moving the keyword lookup into something like:

```
def before(job)
    # If keyword doesn't exist, destroy job
    begin
        @keyword = Keyword.find(keyword_id)
    rescue 'RecordNotFound'
        self.destroy
    end
end
```

The job fails, so DJ keeps re-attempting this job until it hits whatever retry cap I have specified.

Here's the failure:

```
Keyword Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "keywords".* FROM "keywords" 
    WHERE ("keywords"."id" = 292929) LIMIT 1
AREL (1.1ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" 
    SET "last_error" = '{Couldn''t find Keyword with ID=292929
    ...
    ...
```

I want DJ to just destroy the job as soon as it sees that the keyword doesn't exist, bypassing the whole retry system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have it silently fail without an exception and the job will be gone.

```
  def perform
    if keyword = Keyword.find_by_id(keyword_id)
      data = keyword.scrape
      keyword.details.create!(:text => data[:text])
    end
  end
```

I changed find() to find_by_id() so it won't raise an exception but alternatively you could rescue.

This way, the job just doesn't do anything if the keyword is gone. A job that doesn't raise an exception just goes away.

We use this pattern quite a bit at Collective Idea.

Comment: Well, today I learned `find_by_id` doesn't raise an exception! I'll vote yours as best answer because of the extra explanation. Do you get delayed_job Stackoverflow questions pushed straight to your phone?

Comment: Nope, I just happened to be doing a twitter search for Collective Idea and found it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy solution by avoiding the exception:

```
class ScrapingJob < Struct.new(:keyword_id)
  def perform
      keyword = Keyword.find_by_id(keyword_id)
      unless keyword.nil?
          data = keyword.scrape
          keyword.details.create!(:text => data[:text])
      end
   end
end
```